# Export DateListPlot graphic as PDF misses elements

Tags: graphics, export, pdf-format

When I try to `Export` a `DateListPlot` as a PDF file:

```
Export["Desktop/test4.pdf", 
 DateListPlot[Transpose[{time, data}], Joined -> False, 
  PlotMarkers -> Automatic, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> 0.5]]
```

the resulting PDF file does not contain the frame labels, ticks and the grid lines. When I select the graphic and use the "export selection as" function, selecting PDF, it works fine. Also when I export the graphic as PNG or JPG etc. it works fine.  This behaviour began with Mathematica version 10.4.1.0 on MacOSX 10.11.5.

Does anybody know what needs to be fixed here? Some configuration file? Or an update of the Java exporter?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this: [Comparison of PDF and original](http://i.stack.imgur.com/w7i6R.png) (same version, but Windows)

Comment: I presume it has to do with some MacOSX configuration/setting that is not correct. But how to fix this? Wolfram's technical support has no solution.

Comment: Could fix the problem finally by performing a Mathematica "clean start" by holding option and shift key while starting Mathematica. This resets all options to their default settings, but it fixed the error.

Answer (score 1):

Could fix the problem finally by performing a Mathematica "clean start" by holding option and shift key while starting Mathematica. This resets all options to their default settings, but it fixed the error.